# Change permalink structure and keep old one

Tags: wordpress, seo, permalinks

I have a site in WordPress with permalink structure "/category/post_id.html" and I would like to change it to "/category/year/month/date/post_id". I know the best practice for permalink is to include post name in URL but I don't want to do that for some reason. My posts have a lot of Social shares/likes so I want to be able to keep those Social shares and likes and upgrade to a new permalink structure mentioned above.

Please help. Any suggestions will be deeply appreciated. Thank You

Comment: You can redirect #301, Your old url to new, It is keep your social benefits and seo raking.

Answer (score -1):

Go to admin -> settings -> permalinks -> select date and time from common settings and then save settings

Hope it will work

Comment: How do I keep the Old ones??

Comment: put this in custom structure textfield

/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%post_id%/

Comment: But that would change the Structure for old Posts too.Which would change the Social Share count to Zero. I don't want to do that..